# If I wanted to host a site that used the web3 api, would I need it to interact with the blockchain?

Tags: web3js, dapps, metamask

I want to host a site to interact with Web3 clients (MetaMask, etc.). I want my site to be able to send transactions, etc. to the clients through the Web3 API for educational purposes.

I don't care if the transactions don't go through, but does my site actually need to have a local blockchain instance running to allow me to produce transactions for people using MetaMask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MetaMask connects to ethereum nodes automatically, without the user having to host one.

Also, if the user has MetaMask installed, your application will have the `web3` object injected automatically in the page and it will be able to use it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Infura is the default Ethereum provider for MetaMask. MetaMask currently injects Web3 version `0.20.3`.

From Truffle documentation:

> Infura is a hosted Ethereum node cluster that lets your users run your
>   application without requiring them to set up their own Ethereum node
>   or wallet. You may not be familiar with Infura by name, but if you've
>   used MetaMask then you've used Infura, as it is the Ethereum provider
>   that powers MetaMask.

Context:

- https://infura.io
- https://media.consensys.net/why-infura-is-the-secret-weapon-of-ethereum-infrastructure-af6fc7c77052